# show a div atleast one checkbox is checked using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angularjs , i need to show a div having delete,rename and move buttons when is click an image(contained a ckeckbox) in a gallery.there are large number of image are present, i need to show the div atleast one checkbox is checked using angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

try below code which should help you to solve your purpose:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="isChecked = !isChecked;">Show Div</input>
        <br>
        <div style="width:200px;height:200px;" ng-show="isChecked">
            Hello Div!!!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```